# Problem with algorithm2e and portuguese option

Tags: symbols, languages, algorithm2e

I have this little algorithm with two For statements and one if-else. I'm using the option `portuguese` on the preamble and here's the problem: instead of displaying the words  "*faça*" and "*fim*" (do and end, respectively), I get "*hacer*" and "*fin*".

Here's my preamble:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage{lmodern}            
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{color}      
\usepackage{graphicx}       
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[brazilian,hyperpageref]{backref}    
\usepackage[alf]{abntex2cite}
\usepackage[portuguese]{algorithm2e}
```

And here's the code:

```
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[htbp]
\SetAlgoLined
\LinesNumbered
\Dados{audio, tamanho, nivel, filtro, ch}
\Entrada{i, j, inicio, comprimento}
\BlankLine
$inicio \leftarrow 0$\;
  $comprimento \leftarrow tamanho$\;
\Para{$i \leftarrow 0$ \Ate $i<nivel$}{
    $inicio \leftarrow 0$\;
$comprimento \leftarrow tamanho/2^{i-1}$\;
\Para{$j \leftarrow 0$ \Ate $j<2^{i-1}$}{
        \eSe{j é par}{
                transformada\_wavelet(audio[inicio],comprimento, 1,'n', filtro, ch)\;
            }{
                transformada\_wavelet(audio[inicio],comprimento, 1,'i', filtro, ch)\;
            }
        }
}
\caption{A DWT-packet}
\label{alg:dwtp}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

The result (i'm using pdfLaTeX on Windows):

```
...
para i ← 0 até i < nível hacer
...
para j ← 0 até j < 2^(i-1) hacer
...
```

If I put `\SetKwFor{Para}{para}{fa\c{c}a}{fim para}` on the TeX file, I get the right output. But this command is on the package already. Why doesn't it work?

Comment: Hi Luan, [welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) `:)` Interesting question. I suspect something related to the later expansion of `\Para`, since both `spanish` and `portuguese` share the same macro name for it.

Comment: I get "faça" out of the box.

Comment: I also get `hacer` (`algorithm2e` 2013/01/06 v5.00). It seems to be version dependent.

Comment: I checked and my system is using an old version: Package `algorithm2e' Release 4.01 -- december 14 2009, and I do not get **hacer** with the old version.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot, I get the correct output using ShareLaTeX: the version used there is 3.10, according to the log.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a nasty bug in `algorithm2e`. The setting of the "localized keywords" is not language dependent and the same keyword `Para` is defined for Portuguese and Spanish. The latter has been added in the last revision of the package and

```
\SetKwFor{Para}{para}{hacer}{fin para}
```

appears later than the similar definition in the Portuguese section, thus overriding it.

Solving such a bug requires a different treatment of keywords, that keeps track of the language option, which presently the package doesn't do.

The only solution is what you found: issuing

```
\SetKwFor{Para}{para}{fa\c{c}a}{fim para}
```

after loading `algorithm2e`.

Please, mention this to the package author.

Comment: It worked, they updated the package in 2015 (but I checked again only today lol). There's no more need to add that extra command since version 5.1. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use an old version of the package. With *algorithm2e* Release4.01, december 14, 2009, I do not have this problem as you can see:

[image: LaTeX output]